# Getting error while executing jquery $.getJSON() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am developing sample jQuery Plugin which loads data from a JSON response.

I don't why, but it is not calling the success method. It is going to .error() method. Can any one help me on this?

`http://www.technicalkeeda.com/demos/load_scroll_content` returns a proper JSON response.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () { 

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://www.technicalkeeda.com/demos/load_scroll_content', function(data) {           
        alert("success");
    },"json").success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function(xhr, testStatus, error) {

        alert('Error' + xhr.status);
        alert('Error' +xhr.response);
        alert('Error' +xhr.responseText);

    })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });   
    jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });

});
</script>
```

Response from Service

```
[[{"EMPLOYEE_ID":"1","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Yashwant Chavan"},{"EMPLOYEE_ID":"2","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Mahesh Diwan"},{"EMPLOYEE_ID":"3","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Rajesh Limaye"},{"EMPLOYEE_ID":"4","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Pankaj Patil"}]]
```

Comment: That's not a JSONP service.

Comment: @Slaks , So I need to the changes on Server side, to work it properly , SO do you have any idea what i need to changes,?

Comment: Is `technicalkeeda.com` your domain?  Is this code running on the same domain?

Comment: What is this plugin supposed to do?  Does the user have to set up the JSON server, or is that always going to be the same URL?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something...why are you passing `"json"` to the `$.getJSON` call?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) callback parameter, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.technicalkeeda.com/demos/load_scroll_content?callback=?');
```

The jQuery ajax function will replace the last ? to a random string like 'jQuery12345' and the response should use the callback parameter value like this:

```js
jQuery12345([
  {"EMPLOYEE_ID":"1","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Yashwant Chavan"},
  {"EMPLOYEE_ID":"2","EMPLOYEE_NAME":"Mahesh Diwan"}
])
```

You can read more about JSON here:

- http://www.json-p.org/
- http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/